# Simple dynamic directives (with dynamic controllers and scope)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have what I feel like should be a fairly simple problem. I am working within a TypeScript + Angular application.

In a controller, I have an array of similar `directives` I'd like to use. These are `panels` I'm using throughout my app.

I'll give them various attributes like a `controller`, `templateUrl`, `data`, etc. They look something like this in my controller:

```
public panels: IPanelConfig[] = [
    {
        controllerName: "MenuController",
        templateUrl: "menu/menu.html",
        data: // an object with some boring stuff in it
    },
    {
        controllerName: "AnotherController",
        templateUrl: "another/this/is/arbitrary.html",
        data: {}
    }
];
```

In my `view`, I loop through each `panel` and use a generic `directive` called `panel` that handles the rest of the work. Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="panel in vm.panels">
    <div panel
         paneldata="panel.data"
         templateurl="panel.templateUrl"
         ctrl="panel.controllerName"></div>
</div>
```

My custom `panel` directive looks like this:

```
module App {
    "use strict";

    export class Panel {

        public link:(scope:angular.IScope, element:angular.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs:angular.IAttributes) => void;
        public restrict:string = "EA";
        public controller:string = "@";
        public name: string = 'ctrl';
        public replace:boolean = true;
        public scope:any = {"paneldata": "="};

        constructor() {
            console.log("panel directive constructor");
        }

        public compile(el, attrs){
            el.append("<div ng-include='\"components/panels/" + attrs.templateurl + "\"'>");
        }
    }

    // add the directive to the angular module
    angular.module("app").directive("panel", [() => new App.Panel()]);

}
```

And finally, I have one of the dynamic controllers set up. In this case, it's `MenuController`. It's pretty boring and looks like this:

```
module App {
    "use strict";

    export class MenuController {

        public scope: any = null;
        public items: IMyItems[] = null;
        public panelData: any = null;
        public dataService: IDataService = null;

        static $inject = ["$scope", "DataService"];

        constructor($scope: any, DataService: IDataService) {

            $scope.vm = this;
            this.scope = $scope;
            this.dataService = DataService;

            $scope.$watch("paneldata", (v) => { this.panelData = v; });
            this.init();

        }

        public init() {
            this.dataService.someRequestToGetItems().then((results) => {
                this.items = results; // <--- the problem!!! :(
            });
        }

    }

    // add the controller to the module
    angular.module("app").controller("MenuController", App.MenuController);

}
```

At this point, *everything* works like I expect it to. `panelData` is populated, the appropriate `view` and `controller` are used, it seems like I am *so close*, but it's not quite there yet.

**The Problem:**
The trouble is when I try to use an `ng-repeat` on the `MenuController`'s `items` array. The view behaves as if `items` is empty (and it is not -- a simple `console.log()` proves it contains what I expect).

**Worth Noting:**
I had originally built a `Menu` directive with the same functionality. The `view`, request to get `items` and ability to loop through, take in a `panelData` attribute, etc. all worked perfectly. It wasn't until I attempted to make this more dynamic that I ran into trouble.

**What I really want:**
It seems silly to me to have this extra `panel` directive to funnel through when each panel could just have its own directive (which is kind of how I started). What I *really* want to be able to do is something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="panel in vm.panels">
    <div {{ panel.directiveName }} paneldata="panel.data"></div>
</div>
```

But that doesn't work.

I would love any suggestions or guidance!

---

**Update**

I had a hunch that this issue may be related to `scope`, but I added a:

```
public test: string = "A test";
```

to my `MenuController` and displayed it successfully in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Well... this doesn't *quite* solve the "why isn't this working" question I was asking originally (and I feel silly for not trying this a while ago), but another way to get around my problem (and handle dynamic directives/controllers), is adding:

```
el.append("<div " + attrs.directivename + " paneldata='" + attrs.paneldata + "'></div>");
```

to my `panel` directive's `compile()` function instead of doing a template with an `ng-include`. I still need to have a directive "funnel" but this will solve my problem for now (and hopefully for someone else who stumbles upon this!).